# JS play videos and images in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am trying to play videos and images in sequence in html. I know it's not possible to play videos and images in sequence using html5 video player. I know generating  video out of images and video is one solution but My scope very limited i need to play videos and images in html5 only. Is there any libraries or solution to achieve this.

Comment: Encoding video stream is a resource intensive task you better emulate images playing as video rather than using some lib. to convert them in html5

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a gallery? https://html5box.com/html5gallery/ is an option.

> jQuery Image and Video Gallery Plugin - Awesome Image and Video Gallery, Supports Images, Flash, YouTube, Vimeo, MP4, M4V, OGG, OGV and WebM Videos, Works on Android, iPhone, iPad, Windows Phone and All Modern Web Browsers

[...]

> Multiple Galleries on One Page: You can create multiple photo or video galleries on one webpage without any extra settings.